# iframe with port :3838 does not work (shinyapp)

Tags: r, iframe, shiny, rstudio, r-markdown

I made a shiny app that I am hosting in an ec2 instance, here is the url

http://www.derek-corcoran-barrios.com:3838/WhereToLive/

I have a website that I build with R:

http://www.derek-corcoran-barrios.com

One of the tabs is supposed to have an iframe of that url: This is the code of the Rmd

````
---
title: "Donde vivir"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

<iframe src="http://www.derek-corcoran-barrios.com:3838/WhereToLive/"style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:5%; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:95%"">
````

For some reason that I don't understand instead of showing an Iframe, it shows the code of the iframe as you can see in the webpage

http://www.derek-corcoran-barrios.com/DondeVivir.html

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

I am using firefox as a browser

Comment: Looks like some formatting issues in your iframe tag? The double-double quotes at the end. Try `<iframe src="http://www.derek-corcoran-barrios.com:3838/WhereToLive/" style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:5%; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:95%">`

Comment: Thank you @gregL could you post that as an answer? I would like to choose it as the answer and give you credit for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some formatting issues in your iframe tag? The double-double quotes at the end.

Try

```
<iframe src="http://www.derek-corcoran-barrios.com:3838/WhereToLive/" style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:5%; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:95%">
```